# Is there any integration for a textarea wysiwyg and Aurelia?

Tags: textarea, aurelia

I'm currently using Summernote

It looks pretty much like this:
Demo http://aurelia-tinymce-sample.sukobuto.com/

github https://github.com/sukobuto/aurelia-tinymce-sample

But this works with nodejs so I can't really bind tons of textareas,

I found this list of all the WYSIWYG with reviews on each but none seems to be fully integrated with aurelia

https://github.com/iDoRecall/comparisons/blob/master/JavaScript-WYSIWYG-editors.md

Any ideas or tips to avoid nodejs?

Comment: I have an example using CKEDITOR, globally installed. Do you have any interest?

Comment: I do if it's with aurelia binding and not a node.js like the one I have :), it probably works with alloyeditor as well

Comment: Yeah, it works with aurelia binding. The only problem is that I had to load it separately, using <script></script> tags. CKEDITOR has to load some files asynchronously, and I still didn't figure out how to load it properly using webpack. It works very well, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT:**
>
> This question
>   [Using CKEditor with Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591654/using-ckeditor-with-aurelia/38598164#38598164)
>   has a better example of how to use CKEDITOR with Aurelia. You should
>   use that.

---

Here's an example using CKEDITOR.

JS - input-editor.js

```
import {inject, bindable, bindingMode, containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
@inject(Element)
export class InputEditor {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;
  @bindable name;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  updateValue() {
    this.value = this.textArea.value;
  }

  bind() {
    this.textArea = this.element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    let editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.textArea);
    this.editorName = editor.name;
    editor.on('change', (e) => {
      this.value = e.editor.getData();
    });
  }

}
```

HTML input-editor.html

```
<template>
  <textarea change.trigger="updateValue()"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name.bind="name" value.bind="value" />
</template>
```

Now, you just have to use it like this:

```
<input-editor value.bind="someProperty">
</input-editor>
```

I still haven't figured out how to properly load CKEDITOR with webpack/systemJS, because CKEDITOR has to load some files asynchronously. So, I had to load it globally, using `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="/layout/js/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The loading approach is not that good, but it works fine.

Comment: You probably would want to add code to remove the 'change' event handler in the unbind callback.

Comment: In the past, I used to remove the 'change' event and call CKEDITOR.destroy() in the detached() callback, but I would get an error saying that the element doesn't exist anymore. This should be fixed using unbind instead detached. Thank you for reminding me! I'll updated this answer.

Comment: `unbind` won't work either. See https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/348.

Answer (score 0):

Froala offers a WYSIWYG editor that looks really nice, however I've not used it yet, and it does have a license.

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor