# How to use Froala Editor in Aurelia with aurelia-cli

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, wysiwyg, aurelia

How to use Froala Editor in Aurelia by using aurelia-cli. I am using typescript syntax.

I had done `au install aurelia-froala-editor`
It installed the editor. But I don't know how to import the editor to use in the HTML file.

Hey is there any other wysiwyg editors that I can use in aurelia?
I have seen this link [Using CKEditor with Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591654/using-ckeditor-with-aurelia)
but it is done in ESnext syntax but I am using typescript. Can any on help me with this?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you have usage explained on the GitHub repository for the plugin: https://github.com/froala/aurelia-froala-editor

Comment: I've read it but couldn't implement it

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get any errors? Using it in HTML is defined here: https://github.com/froala/aurelia-froala-editor#usage

Comment: Well, the problem is that it does not work for aurelia-cli. It has been reported in the issues section also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an update couple of days ago on the Aurelia integration and there are detailed instructions for Aurelia CLI now: https://github.com/froala/aurelia-froala-editor#with-aurelia-cli.

Answer (score 1):

simply add in `main.ts` after the npm install:

```
 .aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-froala-editor'), config => {
  config.options({
    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'fullscreen', 'undo', 'redo'],
  })
});
```